# How can I convert CSV file into an integer array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, int, genetic

I have a CSV file including integer numbers :
[image: x.csv]

I convert it into an String array:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("x.csv"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split("\n");
            x_values.add(Arrays.asList(values));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is like this :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8GhN.png)

but I want to use values as integer numbers and find their average. How can I do that?

Comment: Is that the real format of the integers or just how they are displayed in a spreadsheet? Please post (correct) sample values as text to your question.

Comment: Start by fixing the code you have. Use your debugger. Use println in the code to understand what you're doing. Splitting a line on "\n" doesn't make much sense. Once you really have an array of Strings, parse each string into an integer.

Comment: You can use `Integer.parseInt(text)` on the individual strings and collect them into `int[]`. Sounds like a bad approach in general though. Go OOP, create a dedicated class to logically represent the data you have per line. Give it a `parseLine` method that creates it from a given line. Then simply read doing `List<Foo> foos = Files.lines(Paths,get("file.csv")).map(Foo::parseLine).collect(Collectors.toList());` - modern Java, hurray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing your lines as `String` values, not as `Integers`. Judging from your image your integers are in exponential notation, meaning you would have to parse them first as double, and then cast them to an integer:

```
    List<Integer> x_values = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("x.csv"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split("\n");
            List<Integer> intValues = Arrays.asList(values).stream()
                    .map(Double::parseDouble) // parse x.xxE+02 to xxx.0
                    .map(Double::intValue) // xxx.0 to integer xxx
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // back to List
            x_values.addAll(intValues);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You should make sure though that your csv file only contains integers, otherwise use `List<Double> x_values` instead and skip the int conversion.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more modern and concise answer

```
     List<Integer> x_values = new ArrayList<>();

     try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("x.csv"))) {
         List<Integer> intValues = br.lines()
                 .map(Double::parseDouble) // parse x.xxE+02 to xxx.0
                 .map(Double::intValue) // xxx.0 to integer xxx
                 .collect(Collectors.toList()); // back to List
         x_values.addAll(intValues);

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```